# Gdbserver: "Port already in use" in Delphi 11 when trying to launch with debugger

Tags: android, debugging, delphi, firemonkey, gdbserver

I am trying to run an Android app in Delphi 11 with the debugger, but it doesn't work.

When starting with the debugger, the progress dialogue gets stuck at the end. When canceling it, the following message appears:

> Unable to start gdbserver on port '64311'. Port already in use

The app is getting launched on the device and runs normally, but without attaching the debugger.

Something to note is that the debugger works on fresh new projects, but not on my existing project. The existing project was originally created in Delphi 10.4.

I have found several threads and posts trying to deal with this issue, but nothing has worked for me. I tried different ports with start parameters, but that just changed the above message to whatever port I used. Restarting the device and PC didn't help, and neither did switching to a different device.

Are there other ways I can try to make it work on my main project?

Comment: Did you try to Clean your project before Build ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug that you should take up with Embarcadero directly.

Comment: I had this problem with a project created with an old version (maybe Tokyo), I create a new project copy all the forms and it was ok, I think there was something bad in the dproj

Comment: @Bosshoss Yes, I tried cleaning, that sadly didn't help either.
So you just created a new project and adjusted it to match the old one? That seems like something I could try. If that doesn't work, I might have to do what Remy suggested.